# How i can use filter in podio api for fields phone?

Tags: php, podio

I need to get item that have this phone (example: 4355510510).

I wanted to use a filter method

```
$items = \PodioItem::filter(PODIO_APP_PHONE_CONTACT_ID2, array(
    'filters' => array(
        163435890=>[4355510510]
     )
        ));
print_r($items);
```

And I got this error

```
Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Filtering not supported for fields of type phone"
```

How can I get items that have the phone I need?

I can not use this example

```
$items = \PodioItem::filter(PODIO_APP_PHONE_CONTACT_ID2, array(
    'limit' => 500,
    'offset'=>0
));

 foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach($item->fields['phones']->values as $phone){
         if(inval($phone) == 4355510510){
             $needMeItems[] = $item;
             break;
         }
    }
}
// rest code
```

Because I have more than 1000 items and each item has 1 or 2 unique phone numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, filtering is not supported for `phone` field. If you need to get item with specific phone you may use search or iterate over items. You may also consider re-design your app if phone number is the only way of getting to needed item.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using `PodioSearchResult`:

```
$search_results = PodioSearchResult::app($app_id, array('query' => '4355510510') );
```

At least this is how I do it :)